# Append variable string to itself

Tags: bash, variable

I have a variable into a do loop. I append its content to a file, but I want to append it to itself so I could use it to do other stuff like sending mail.

I tried `variable+=$variable` but it didn't work.

I want to have access to the variable outside the do...done

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181703/how-can-i-concatenate-string-variables-in-bash AND here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250131/how-do-you-append-to-an-already-existing-string - Cheers :)

Comment: What do you mean by “didn't work”? Did you have an error message? Was the variable's resulting value not what you expecting? Post your code.

Comment: Why not just `variable="$variable$variable"`? I'll bet it's more portable than `+=`.

Answer (score 6):

I bet your loop is part of a pipeline

```
seq 5 | while read num; do x+=$num; done; echo $x 
# expect "12345", actually see ""
```

In bash, when you construct a pipeline, it spawns subshells for all the parts. When the subshell exits, any variables you modify within it are destroyed too.

You have to code more carefully to ensure you use the variable in the same shell where you modify it.

This example echoes the var in the same subshell:

```
$ seq 5 | { while read num; do x+=$num; done; echo $x; }
12345
```

This example uses [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) so the loop runs in the current shell

```
$ while read num; do x+=$num; done < <(seq 5)
$ echo $x
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are just strings you can append like this:

#### Example

```
$ somevar="a string"
$ echo $somevar
a string

$ somevar="$somevar$somevar"

$ echo $somevar
a stringa string
```

#### Loops

You can use the same technique in a `for` loop in Bash.

```
$ a="0"; for i in $(seq 3); do a="$a$i"; echo "$i | $a"; done
1 | 01
2 | 012
3 | 0123
```